# XSLT convert HTML special characters despite output method is html

Tags: html, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<record
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim http://www.loc.gov/standards/marcxml/schema/MARC21slim.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
....
  <datafield tag="856" ind1=" " ind2=" ">
    <subfield code="u">https://koha-test.pinoysystemslibrarian.info/cgi-bin/koha/opac-retrieve-file.pl?id=1362f36c9e3198f7ed369692140c4746</subfield>
  </datafield>
....
```

And the following xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE stylesheet>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:marc="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
  exclude-result-prefixes="marc str">
    <xsl:import href="MARC21slimUtils.xsl"/>
    <xsl:output method = "html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration = "yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="marc:record">

.... [Ommitted]

        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$OPACEnableEbookReader='1'">
                <xsl:attribute name="href">/ebookreader/?d=<xsl:value-of select="str:encode-uri(marc:subfield[@code='u'], true())"/>&amp;ref=<xsl:value-of select="translate('$OPACBaseURL', '%2F', '/')"/>/cgi-bin/koha/opac-detail.pl?biblionumber=<xsl:value-of select="$biblionumber"/></xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>     
            <xsl:otherwise>
```

What I wanted to do is that my xslt should convert HTML special characters like "/" and ":". I've tried **translate** to convert "%2F" which should be "/", which is in this line in my code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate('$OPACBaseURL', '%2F', '/')"/>
```

However, this is not being translated or converted. How do I go about this even though my output method is "html"? The OPACBaseURL is a variable which is a URL like so: https://example.com.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

This is very confusing.

If you have a string that contains `%2F` and you want to convert it to `/`, you need to use the `str:decode-uri()` function, not the `translate()` function - for example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="myVar">abc%2Fdef</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="str:decode-uri($myVar)"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>abc/def</result>
```

Note also that the reference to the variable is *not* quoted.

Comment: Hi! Apparently, removing the translate function, just simply this code:<xsl:value-of select="$OPACBaseURL"/> gives me what I want.  It was probably that I didn't restart a 
program while trying out translate in between. Thanks!